# does Page.User make a call do the database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, membership

I was using `Membership.getUser()` to get the currently logged in user but I recently discovered that each time this it called, the data is retrieved from the database.

If `page.user` also makes a call to the db then how can I get the currently logged on user without continuously hitting the db.

It would be difficult to store and manage this object in session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Page.User` will not hit the DB.

You can get the name of the currently logged in user from `HttpContext` without hitting the DB.

```
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

OR

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `HttpContext.User.Identity` [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Page.Title = "Home page for " + User.Identity.Name;
}
else
{
    Page.Title = "Home page for guest user.";
}
```